# XMLHttpRequest wrapper using fetch for chrome extension service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

We have mansifest 2 chrome extension which is using Asp.Net SignalR, Twilio Voice, Twilio Conversation and other websockets and other js libraries. We are migrating to manifest v3. Now most of them are using XMLHttpRequest internally to communicate with servers. Since there is no XMLHttpRequest api in service worker, only fetch is available. Is there any wrapper for it using fetch api as most of them are large libs and modifying them its a complex approach. Most of them are not available on CDN and only can be downloaded using npm. I was also using axios which also gave error so I transform it to below code.

```
const HttpClient = {
    get: async (endpoint, customConfig = {}) => {
        const token = await getItem('token');
        const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        if (token) {
            headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token.accessToken}`
        }
        const config = {
            method: 'GET',
            ...customConfig,
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                ...customConfig.headers,
            }
        }
        return global
            .fetch(endpoint, config)
            .then(async response => {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    sendUnAuthorizedEvent();
                    return;
                }
                const data = await response.json();
                if (response.ok) {
                    return { data };
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject({ response: { data } });
                }
            })
    },
    post: async (endpoint, body, customConfig = {}) => {
        const token = await getItem('token');
        const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        if (token) {
            headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token.accessToken}`
        }
        const config = {
            method: 'POST',
            ...customConfig,
            headers: {
                ...headers,
                ...customConfig.headers,
            }
        }
        if (body) {
            config.body = JSON.stringify(body)
        }
        return global
            .fetch(endpoint, config)
            .then(async response => {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    sendUnAuthorizedEvent();
                    return;
                }
                const data = await response.json();
                if (response.ok) {
                    return { data };
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject({ response: { data } });
                }
            });
    }
}


export default HttpClient;
```

Need help how can I overcome this XMLHttpRequest issues.

Comment: If you want to write a wrapper yourself and encountered a specific problem you can show [MCVE](/help/mcve) for your attempt i.e. what exactly is not working, what exactly is happening, what exactly should happen. Otherwise this question should be closed as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more".

Comment: I am asking XMLHttpRequest and Fetch both have different features and way of working. How do I start to write this wrapper.

Comment: Just make a new `class` with all methods of XMLHttpRequest and re-implement them via fetch. Not all features can be mapped trivially of course, that's where you can show your progress here on stackoverflow, which would be a focused and practically answerable question.

Comment: @wOxxOm One question can we pass window object from content script to service worker and add a global window there ? is it possible ?

Comment: No, messaging can't pass `window` or DOM objects. Why would you need it here?

Comment: I am using twilio for voice, calls and messaging, their libs using window heavily in their features.

Comment: My extension is for taking calls in browser using websockets, webrtc. So background persistency doesn't break calls on page refreshes. Now service worker doesn't have window now.

Comment: Libraries use the current `window`. Passing a window from another page won't help you. Service workers simply don't have these technologies by design, so you'll need to open a new tab or embed an extension frame into the web page via `web_accessible_resources` - BTW this will allow you using all DOM libraries and XMLHttpRequest and parent.postMessage and MessageChannel to pass streams and so on. The only restriction is that it will be closed along with the tab.

Comment: Yes we can use content script but when page refreshes all websockets and calls got dropped. So thats why we were using background js for all websockets connections.

Comment: That's not a content script I'm talking about. It's a separate chrome-extension:// iframe.

Comment: Our current extension content script embeded into a div on current page where our app shows up. Client can open and close by showing and hiding a div on that page.

Comment: Like I said, an iframe is a different thing.

Comment: Can you guide me to an example or code ? Are you talking about a page just like options page opened up?

Comment: There are many, here's the keywords to search: `extension iframe web_accessible_resources`. You can also add specific things you look for like the library name.

Comment: Thanks, basically open a tab and inject iframe into that tab. or show the app inside that tab. I am using react in frontend.